# ASP.Net C# ListView inline conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net

In have a list of objects bound to a ListView that is used to make a nice list of these items. In this ListView I have 1 column that shoud have a specific condition to display a specific string. Is this possible using inline code or should I get a workaround using the codebehind?

This is what I would like to do:

```
<% if (((Recipe)Container.DataItem).Status == RecipesModel.REJECTED) { %>
Something goes here
<% } %>
```

But this returns this exception:

```
The name 'Container' does not exist in the current context
```

**EDIT**: this code is used inside `<ItemTemplate>`

**EDIT 2**: I found myself using the following code for this problem:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder id="place_public" runat="server" Visible='<%# ((Recipe)Container.DataItem).Status == RecipesModel.VALIDATED %>'>
Something here
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Comment: It seems like Container doesnt exist in that context...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot use `Container.DataItem` outside of data binding context

try something like

```
<%# Container.DataItem ... %>
```

eg:

```
<%# ((String)Container.DataItem).ToUpper() == "test" ? "IsTest" : "NotTest" %>
```

Comment: But then I can not use it to test a condition

Comment: Is it possible to test it against the constant from the RecipesModel class like in my code?

Comment: it is possible. but since it's a howework question, you should try it yourself following my example. Hint: replace String with Recipe and ToUpper() with your Status property.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to import the namespace of the container class in your .aspx page.
for example:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Container Class namespace" %>
```

Comment: I did not write my own Container class, this is the ListView's container. I don't know what namespace I should include.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use the Container object outside of its scope.  Can you post the rest of the code so we can see what is happening on the page?

Comment: This code is used inside the ItemTemplate tags. Expressions like <%# Eval("status") %> work, but I want to test a certain condition in these values.